# Would I have to purchase two Gears of War 3 season passes?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I play multiplayer and Co-op with my boyfriend on the same Xbox console. I was thinking of getting the season pass for the DLC but would I need to buy two, one pass for each of us? Are they just registered to your accounts or will the DLC be available on the console for us to both use?

Comment: Buy one a test it? Get a second if needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are both always playing on the same console, then I don't think it is necessary to build two season passes.

All DLC and XBLA games have the following licensing restrictions:

- All GamerTags on your home console (i.e. where you normally play, and you (probably) originally downloaded the item) can use it
- Your GamerTag can use the item on another console, assuming the console is connected to LIVE.

So as long as all the Gears 3 uses the standard Xbox LIVE licensing (I don't see why it wouldn't), then you should both be able to use all of the Gears 3 DLC assuming you are both always on the same console.

As an aside, at least for the Versus maps (not sure about Horde mode), but as long as the host has the DLC then everyone can play on the new maps (even if they don't have the DLC).